# ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy a django app on GCP but when i try to make migrations it gives me this error:

> ImportError: Could not import
>   'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication' for API
>   setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ModuleNotFoundError: No
>   module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'.

**Settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=800),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=2),
}
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
        'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 60 * 15,
        'OAUTH_SINGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN': True,
        'OAUTH_DELETE_EXPIRED': True
 }
```

**requirements.txt**

```
django-cors-headers
pyjwt
djangorestframework
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
```

What is it that I am missing ?

**UPDATE**
I installed rest_framework_simplejwt and now the error shifted to :

> No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens'

Comment: What kind of deployment are you doing on GCP? Compute or App Engine?

Comment: App Engine  Deployment

Comment: I was getting this error because I installed `webauthn` and `django-webauth` 
which might updated some packages and I uninstalled them it's fixes the issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems you are confusing two packages. `djangorestframework-jwt` which you have in your requirements.txt is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt). It provides the `rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication` authentication class.

However, the one you are actually using, `rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication`, comes from the pip package [`djangorestframework-simplejwt`](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt)

So you need to update your requirements.txt. Remove `djangorestframework-jwt` and add `djangorestframework-simplejwt`

Comment: Hey, I tried you way, and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 6):

for me the `djangorestframework-simplejwt` upgrade from `4.4.0` to current latest version `4.6.0` fixed the problem.

```
pip3 install --upgrade djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone still encountering this error, this is the requirements for djangorestframework-simplejwt:

```
Python (3.6, 3.7, 3.8)
Django (2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0)
Django REST Framework (3.8, 3.9, 3.10)
```

I downgraded Django & DRF and the problem is solved for me.

```
pip uninstall django
pip uninstall djangorestframework
pip install --upgrade django==3.0
pip install --upgrade djangorestframework==3.10
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

Answer (score 1):

For me issue solverd by restarting virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error when attempting to deploy on Heroku

Upon investigating I found 2 issues in my case:

1]  requirements.txt --> This file was not updated and therefore 'git add' and 'git commit' did not pickup the new requirement for djangorestframework-simplejwt

So the solution here was to do a fresh pip freeze > requirements.txt, git add/commit and confirm that on Heroku

2] Secondly I found that Heroku was not finding the v4.6.0 which my python3.8 had installed locally. Instead, I had to edit the requirements.txt to v4.4.0 (current on the pypi.org), redo the git add/commit before this problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still running into this issue using VS Code and running their Django app inside a Docker container, I solved the issue by downgrading my Python version to 3.9, instead of 3.10, and then rebuilding my container.

In your `Dockerfile` make sure the `FROM python:3.9` matches the current supported version of python on the docs page: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html , in this case, version `3.9`. Mine was set to `3.10` before, which at the time of this writing, isn't supported. Then re-build your docker image.

`docker-compose down`

`docker-compose up -d --build`

Also, if you are using pipenv to manage your packages, change your python version in your `Pipfile`, `python_version = "3.9"`. Then run `pipenv install` to install the change.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was also having installed both djangorestframework-jwt and djangorestframework_simplejwt. After unistalling the former my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you don't have the jwt library installed on your machine.

You can install it with  `pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt` (or `pip3` you're using Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

Depleting virtual environment and creating a new one, install the supported version of drf solved this for me