# cant run django server

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-3.2

I am getting this error and cant start the server. Please help me

```
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt.utils'.
```

full error code:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
(codersavvy) D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 177, in import_from_string
    return import_string(val)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\authentication.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .settings import api_settings
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\settings.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .utils import format_lazy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt.utils'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\codersavvy\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('api/', include('blog.urls')),
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\blog\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 22, in <module>
    from rest_framework import views
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 17, in <module>
    from rest_framework.schemas import DefaultSchema
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    authentication_classes=api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES,
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 225, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 168, in perform_import
    return [import_from_string(item, setting_name) for item in val]
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 168, in <listcomp>
    return [import_from_string(item, setting_name) for item in val]
  File "D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 180, in import_from_string
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt.utils'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864306/importerror-could-not-import-rest-framework-simplejwt-authentication-jwtauthen

Comment: @ManishShah no.doesnot help

Comment: Is `djangorestframework_simplejwt` in your requirements.txt?

Comment: @bdbd yes. already installed