# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklistauthentication'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am experiencing this error caused by the simplejwt framework.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklistauthentication'
```

I want to blacklist used refresh tokens (after refresh). The simplejwt works perfectly but it seems there is an issue caused by `'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'`

Here are my rest_framework configs:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
     ],
      'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

have you tried this

```
pip install --upgrade djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

my issue is

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'

and the error is in version of djangorestframework-simplejwt; or you can readmore at [ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864306/importerror-could-not-import-rest-framework-simplejwt-authentication-jwtauthen)

Answer (score 3):

just write that in tirmanal (pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

please check if there is a comma right after `'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'` in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

That's probably the reason why the name is `'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklistauthentication'` instead of `'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the 'Blacklist' app in installed apps:

`INSTALLED_APPS = ['rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist', ...]`

The documentation explain it: [Blacklisted app](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_app.html).